# Generic type argumented class with generic type argumented Subclass

Tags: c#, class, generics, generic-programming, generic-type-argument

I have one class with a generic type, like this:

```
public class Test<T> {
    /*
       Some Properties and Fields
    */
}
```

Now I need a public Property SubTest{T}  in class Test{T} with datatype Test{T}

```
public class Test<T> {
    /*
       Some Properties and Fields
    */
    public Test<T> SubTest { get; set; }
}
```

T and U are not the same datatype and SubTest can be null.
Is that possible in C#?

**Update**
Or like This?

```
public class Test {
    /*
       Some Properties and Fields
    */
    public Type ElementType { get; private set; }
    public Test SubTest { get; set; }

    public Test(Type elementType) {
        ElementType = elementType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit inconsistent:

> Now I need a public Property SubTest{**T**} in class Test{**T**} with datatype
>   Test{**T**}

But your example is different, and now U has been added.

```
public class Test<T> 
{
    public Test<U> SubTest { get; set; }
}
```

So to answer your question as-is, replace U with T:

```
public class Test<T> 
{
    public Test<T> SubTest { get; set; }
}
```

I think what you are trying to do is to create a generic "test" object, and then have multiple implementations (with different types). I would use interfaces instead, but its the same concept with classes.

```
public interface ITest
{
    // general test stuff
}

// Type-specific stuff
public interface ITesty<T> : ITest
{
     public ITest SubTest { get; set; }    // a sub-test of any type
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it was a bit inconsistent. Thanks for the reply, I had ever tried with interfaces, but not like you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

U it not defined so it cannot be used like the. You need to create type parameter in the class, or use a specific type, for example `string`:

```
public class Test<T, U> {
      /*
         Some Properties and Fields
      */

      public Test<T,U> SubTest { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not i need.